# Send update messages to HTML mid process in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I have a python project in PythonAnywhere where the user uploads a file, it gets processed, and then it gets downloaded again by the user.

The file gets processed using a RandomForestRegressor model.

So far, it works perfectly. The user uploads and a new output file is generated. What I want to do is that the results of the model be returned in the website.

A message like this:

> Accuracy of model on test set: 0.90

> mse of model on train set: 0.08

The HTML is like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
            {% for comment in comments %}
                <div class="row">
                    {{ comment }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I was trying to add a comment after the `proccess_data` function is called. I added the render_template with the comment variable but it doesnt work. I even added it at the end of the `def index()` as a return but it just doesnt work.

```
            output_file = process_data(filename)
            comments = 'File processed succesfully'
            render_template("main_page.html", comments=comments)
```

The python script is like this:

```
comments = []

@app.route('/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("main_page.html")

    if request.method == 'POST':

        #comments.append(request.form["contents"])

        #check if the post request has the file part
        if 'input_file' not in request.files:
            #TODO
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['input_file']

        #if the user does not select a file, the browser submits
        #empty file without a filename
        if file.filename == '':
            #TODO
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            
           
            output_file = process_data(filename)
            comments = 'File processed succesfully'
            render_template("main_page.html", comments=comments)

            si = io.StringIO()
            output_file.to_csv(si,index=False, encoding='UTF8')

            #-----Save dataframe to folder-----
            filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'results.csv')
            output_file.to_csv(filepath)

            response = make_response(si.getvalue())
            response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=results.csv"
            response.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"

            return response

    return
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with python but I see you basically want to send two responses in one request and most likely at different times?

HTTP does not work like that. You can't send one response "mid process" and then some other after a while. It's always one request - one response. And a new tcp connection opens and closes immediately each time.

So if you want to notify user about the results of backend process some time before you actually send him the "final data", you have these options:

1. Divide this flow into multiple individual requests.
2. Use [WebSockets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/).